# Internet Explorer 11 and 0xEF 0xBF 0xBF in XMLHttp response

Tags: xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

If I use ActiveXObject("microsoft.xmlhttp") in IE 11 and send a request, my XML response can be parsed without error. So far so good.

If I turn compatibility mode on and do the same request, the XML response from the server is the same with the exception that it now includes the bytes 0xEF 0xBF 0xBF once in the middle of the stream. Why would turning compatibility mode on cause this? Does it change the encoding which is expected?

Note: The response XML doesn't seem to include any byte with ASCII value greater than 127 when compatibility mode is off.

The site I'm maintaining has hundreds of references to ActiveXObject("microsoft.xmlhttp") else I'd replace them with jQuery, and the site requires compatibility mode which I'd love to fix also but there are hundreds of pages that don't work without it enabled.

I can fix the issue by changing these lines:

```
<!doctype html public "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>
```

to these lines:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

...although this messes up some of the jQgrid CSS used on the same page.

Comment: With refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view/): In the default state, all sites on the public internet display in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode (Compatibility View off) and all intranet websites display in Internet Explorer 7 Standards mode (Compatibility View on). So, I suppose before adding the X-UA-Compatible, the browser using IE 7 Standards, after using it, it will use IE 8 Standards.

Comment: Why would IE 11 with compatibility mode off use IE 8 standards?

Comment: Perhaps the issue relates to the default compatibility mode standards, before adding the X-UA-Compatible, it will use the IE 11 default compatibility standards, after using it, it will use IE 8 Standards. and your application applies to the IE 8 Standards. I will check it, then give your a feedback.